# Error while trying to convert string into JSON - python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to read a string in `JSON` format using this code:

```
data="""{"values": [["c1", 1], ["c2", 6.6], ["c3", 0], ["c4", 0.0066], ["id", 2005742774], ["c5", 1814278934], ["c6", 1000184], ["c7", "2018-04-06 17:18:23"], ["c8", "2018-04-06 17:18:23"], ["c9", "2018-04-06 17:18:23"]]}"""

json.loads(data)
```

This works just fine in this case, but when the string contains `None` , it raises an error. This is the string that is causing the problem:

```
{"values": [["a1", None], ["a2", "https://aaaa.com"], ["a3", "test"], ["a4", None], ["a5", 1814278940], ["a6", "AKJHGDKHG"], ["a7", None], ["dateCreated", "2018-03-06 17:18:39"], ["page_id", 772430], ["dateModified", "2018-03-06 17:18:39"], ["a8", 1]]}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 28 (char 27)
```

**EDIT:**

As **@Jean-François Fabre** suggested, I used `ast.literal_eval` and it worked for the example mentioned above , but not for the example below:

```
{"values": [["a1", "hgjhgkjh"], ["url", "https://example.com"], ["c5", "5464"], ["c4", "39446489"], ["c3", 1814308464], ["session", "AILGHGH"], ["c10", null], ["dateCreated", "2018-03-06 17:23:55"], ["page", 771790], ["dateModified", "2018-03-06 17:23:55"], ["device_id", 168]]}
```

because `c10` is `null`. In fact I can either have `null` or `None` is there a way to deal with this two cases please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json *null* is `null`, not `None`. Your string is not JSON but native Python dict converted to string.

An alternative to `json.load` is `ast.literal_eval` in this case

```
import ast
x = """{"values": [["a1", None], ["a2", "https://aaaa.com"], ["a3", "test"], ["a4", None], ["a5", 1814278940], ["a6", "AKJHGDKHG"], ["a7", None], ["dateCreated", "2018-03-06 17:18:39"], ["page_id", 772430], ["dateModified", "2018-03-06 17:18:39"], ["a8", 1]]}"""
d = ast.literal_eval(x)
```

If you want to be able to accept both native python & json format, you could catch the exception on the first method and try the other one:

```
import ast,json

def load_anything(s):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(s)
    except ValueError:
        return json.loads(s)
```

of course, if you have both `None` and `null` in your string, the method doesn't work. You'll have to use `replace`...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but the problem is that I can have both cases, either `null` or `None`, is there a way to handle bothe cases pleases ?

Comment: many thanks again, when I tried the example you've given it worked but when I do this `load_anything('"""'+data+'"""')` in order to pass the data string with the three double quotes at the beginning and at the end, it returns a string and not a dict

Comment: the triple quotes are for literals... Else you're just parsing a string... Remove the triple quotes. I edited your question because it was incorrect (you weren't defining a string)

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks a lot @Jean-Franois Fabre, i'm very grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert your dict to a JSON string before loading it:

```
json.loads(json.dumps(data))
```

It will automatically convert all `None`'s to `null`'s

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, the only problem is that it returns a `string` instead of `JSON` object

Comment: No it does not, it returns a dict, that is saveable as a json file

Comment: Ofc you have to put in the dict in the first place! No quotation marks around your data!